# How to turn a json string into a properly beautified string to be used in email using a Logic App

Tags: javascript, json, azure-logic-apps

Logic App

[image]

[image]

```
"Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p><br></p>\n<pre><code>Message 1<br>\n<br>\n@{variables('Message1')}<br>\n<br>\nMessage 2<br>\n<br>\n@{variables('Message2')}</code></pre>\n<pre><code><br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n</code></pre>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Test",
                        "To": "test@test.com"
                    }
```

This is how it looks like in the email. I know the Message 2 has it already nicely formatted but I would want both to look the same.

Any ideas are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing issue from my side, I got the expected results by taking **Parse Json Action after initialize variable action**.
As shown in below images i have taken initialize variable actions and send email.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With out parse Json action I got below output in email.
[image]

As shown in below image **in Parse Json action take Content as Message 1 from dynamic content** .
Schema :

```
{
  "Request_Date": "2023-07-18",
  "Number_of_Adults": "5",
  "Number_of_Children": "1",
  "Total_Cost": "690"
}
```

[image]

Then in **Send Email action in body** take your required data from **dynamic content of parse Json 1** as shown in below image.
[image]

Then the logic App ran successfully and email got received with expected output format.
[image]

[image]

Reference [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption) for parse Json.

Comment: The Message structure can change so it will not always be in the same format so the above solution will not work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
replace(replace(replace(variables('Message1'),',',',<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'),'{','{<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'),'}','<br>}')
```